# Do I need to run ForestPrep and DomainPrep after uninstalling Exchange Server 2003?

Tags: exchange-2003, microsoft-office-365

We've migrated our email to Office 365, so I now need to remove our one and only on-premises Exchange Server (2003 Standard).

The documentation that I've read suggests that I:

1. Go to a command prompt (running as Administrator)
2. With the Exchange Server 2003 installation CD in the drive, go to the D:\Setup\i386\ directory and run Update.exe /removeorg
3. Run Setup.exe /forestprep
4. Run Setup.exe /domainprep
5. Done?

Why should I need to run setup.exe /forestprep and setup.exe /domainprep?  There is no explanation of this in what I've read and when I look up what these do, it appears that they prepare for an **installation** of Exchange, not an **uninstallation**.

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the org? Are you operating O365 as a hybrid, or standalone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you visit Technet documentation on uninstalling Exchange.  Simply [uninstalling an Exchange server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125110%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx) is different from [uninstalling the last Exchange server in your environment](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/273478/en-us).  If you need/want [to uninstall Exchange **and** then remove it from AD, visit this article, which lays out the proper order in which to do it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833396).

Rerunning the forest and domain prep operations is recommended, with the intent of allowing Exchange to be reinstalled or installed at a later date.  If you're certain you won't, then, strictly speaking, you don't need to prep the domain and forest again, but given the triviality of the operation (and the fact that your schema has already been extended to allow the Exchange install in the first place), I see no reason not to.

Rerun the forest and domain prep to leave the environment in a proper, pristine state for the next guy or your future self, because it's a good idea, and there's no drawback to doing so.

Comment: Having now uninstalled Exchange 2003 from our server, I now know that Microsoft Exchange Forest Preparation and Domain Preparation are actually performed by the Installation Wizard when you remove Exchange from the server.  No need to run them separately yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Running the "prep" stuff will never hurt your AD, though it does extend AD to include Exchange objects. (Extending AD is irreversible, you can't remove the extensions).
2. Once the "prep" is done it doesn't need to be done again, so you can skip this while uninstalling.
3. Use the Uninstall in Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel if you can, not the CD setup, if you can as your CD might be outdated (typical after installation of Service Packs and the like)

Comment: Hi Chris.  I understand where you're coming from with regards to not using the old installation CD, but how would I run update.exe /removeorg if not from the installation CD?  I would expect that uninstalling via Add/Remove programs will remove the services, files, registry, etc but leave a behind references to the decommissioned server in Active Directory?  Perhaps the answer is to do both?  Thanks, Matty.

Comment: Phew, I'm glad I came across this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830185.  It says "Important Do not use the removeorg option unless you intend to remove Exchange completely from your organization. You must also remove Exchange from your servers before you run the removeorg option. If you try to remove Exchange from the servers after you run the option, the removal process fails. You then must remove Exchange manually."  Will have to make sure I do this in the correct order!  :)